# Making a Moderator Authorized User role for my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, roles

I have 2 types of roles for my user at the moment `[:member , :admin]`, members can CRUD most post created by them . :admin can do CRUD any post period. Now im trying to create a moderator that can only View and update all posts. i have added `:moderator` to my `enum role:`. I also included 
`before_action :moderator_user, except: [:index, :show]` and

```
  def authorize_user
    unless current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You must be an admin to do that."
      redirect_to topics_path
    end
  end
  def moderator_user
    unless current_user.moderator?
      flash[:alert] = "You must be an moderator to do that."
      redirect_to topics_path
    end
  end
```

but seem to be interfering with my   `before_action :authorize_user, except: [:index, :show]` because it causes my rspec tests to fail.

Im trying to figure out how to create a moderator role which will be in between member and admin but without affecting either.

helper.rb :

```
  def user_is_authorized_for_topics?
      current_user && current_user.admin?
  end
  def user_is_moderator_for_topics?
      current_user && current_user.moderator?
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect case for one of the authorization gems -- [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). `CanCanCan` is probably the best for user-centric implementations...

```
#Gemfile
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.13'

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in) #-> looks for "current_user"
    case true
       when user.admin?
         can :manage, Post                   #-> CRUD all
       when user.moderator?
         can [:read, :update], Post          #-> update/read posts
       when user.member?
         can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id #-> CRUD their posts
    end
  end
end
```

The above will give you the ability to use the [`can?` and `authorize` methods](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization) in your controller & views:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end

#app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <% if can? :update, article %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(article) %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above should do well for you.

The [`load_and_authorize_resource`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#load_resource) filter should provide you with *scoped* data:

> As of 1.4 the index action will load the collection resource using accessible_by.
>
> ```
> def index
>   # @products automatically set to Product.accessible_by(current_ability)
> end
> ```

--

There is a great [Railscast about this here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan). The creator of Railscasts authored `CanCan` before getting burned out, so a new community took it up with `CanCanCan`.